# Visual Studio 12 - cannot find basic functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am a Java developer whose project needs one bit of C code (DLL) that I recompile every few years when I upgrade my machine.  My new machine is AMD-64bit (Windows8) so the old 32-bit DLL will not run.

I installed MS Visual Studio 12.  I copied the old project to the new machine.  VS migrated it.  I selected build and prayed that it would work.  Of course, it did not.

I get these two errors:

1>IcmpSocketN.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__printf

1>IcmpSocketN.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___ftime64_s

1>C:\temp\new_March09\ATM\Release\AtiICMP.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

These are two standard functions so I am assuming that VS installed them somewhere.

When I did the install I selected the C++ foundation libraries.  When I look at the project properties I see that the only platform option is Win32.  This is a 64-bit machine.  I do not know if that matters or not.

The VS install on my old machine has a VC subdirectory with a bunch of libraries in it.  The new install has no such directory.

Is there some .lib or .dll that I have to download independently of the VS install?  Some environment variable change?

thanks

Comment: A proper installation of Visual C++ should not need anything just to support printf. Either your installation is incomplete (Does your VS edition support 64 bits? Was there an option to explicitly select something like that during installation?) or your project got corrupted in the 64-bit conversion.

Comment: I ran into an error like this a few time and I would fix it by selecting "Rebuild" a 2nd time, hope this can help.

Comment: if not you can restart your computer, hope it works...

Comment: Having an empty vc\lib subdirectory is not normal and produces this problem.

Comment: Try a clean rebuild, if you copied the obj files it will still have the old references to the old CRT, you'll need to rebuild against the new CRT

Comment: If you want to compile the DLL for x64, just go to the Configuration Manager, and create a new x64 solution platform.

Comment: Are you linking the correct library for sockets?

Comment: I tried several clean builds.  Still no good.  I am now uninstalling VS and will try again.

Comment: I installed something different.  The first install was called vs_community.exe.  The second install was called wdexpress_full.exe.  Same result though.  I am going to create a project from scratch and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Creating a project from scratch and moving in my source files did the trick.  Plus creating the x64 config (thanks ElderBug).